# Questions from the Area 51 site?

Tags: discussion

Is there any plan to post the [questions from the Area 51 site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7551?phase=definition) to the private-beta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think questions should come organically, no need to force questions just because they were asked in the proposal.

Comment: +1 @Soufiane Hassou: Thank you for sharing your take! Guess I just assumed that the existing questions would be automatically imported under a user's profile when the private-beta started; not that I asked any questions for the chess proposal, just in general how I thought they'd be used. Thanks for posting an answer, going wait to select an answer, since neither of us have done a private-beta before.

Comment: yeah, grow organically!